# show another (permanent) button after clicked button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display another button after I clicked on the existing button, but i want that the new button created stays permanently on the page, no disappear when i refresh the page. Any clue?

```js
function addBtn(){
  document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '<input type="button"  value="Click" />';
}
```

```html
<div id=btnOne> <input type=button onClick=javascript:addBtn(); value='Click' /></div>
<div id=btnHolder></div>
```

Comment: To do this, you'll need to store that configuration either in a cookie (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or in a local database (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Answer (score 0):

You could always use your browsers `window.localStorage` like this:

```
<body>

    <div id=btnOne> <input type=button onClick=javascript:addBtn(); value='Click' /></div>
    <div id=btnHolder></div>

    <script>
        const buttonStorage = window.localStorage;

        console.log(buttonStorage.getItem('button'));

        function addBtn(){
          document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '<input type="button"  value="Click" />';
          buttonStorage.setItem('button', true);
        }

        if(buttonStorage.getItem('button')) {
          document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '<input type="button"  value="Click" />';
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Full Disclosure: This will work in your browser so long as you include your script **at the end** of your html body (last line) like the above code example so it can find the html elements. If the user switches browsers there will still only be one button. If you want that kind of functionality you will have to do it server side.

To find more out about Local Storage you can [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @Flory Any progress on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can put a cookie on the browser of the user and check on the load of the page if the cookie exist like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Stack Overflow</title>
<body onload="checkBtn()">
<div id=btnOne> <input type=button onClick=javascript:addBtn(); value='Click' /></div>
<div id=btnHolder style="display:none"><input type="button"  value="Click" /></div>
<script>
function addBtn(){
    if(getCookie("btn"))
        document.getElementById('btnHolder').style.display = ''; 
    document.getElementById('btnHolder').style.display = ''; 
    setCookie("btn",true,5);
  }
function checkBtn(){
    if(getCookie("btn"))
        document.getElementById('btnHolder').style.display = ''; 
  }
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
              var d = new Date();
              d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
              var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
              document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
          }
function  getCookie(cname){
            return (document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+ cname +'=([^;]*)')||0)[2]
        }

</script>
</body>
```

if you want delete the cookie, you have to use :

```
delCookie(cname) {
            document.cookie = cname+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
        }
```

like that :

Answer (score -1):

There is a way, you can use **localStorage**.

Basicly when you enter the page he checks the storage if some button is added

```
localStorage.getItem('addedBtn');
```

in the code above, you check if the addedBtn key exist on your browser storage, if not mantain the logic of your button (clicking will add the btn), but it will not just add the button, it will also add a new entry to the storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('addedBtn', 'value');
```

the above code receives the key and you can pass the value, in this case you can just see if in the storage the key already exist.

**full code**

```
function addBtn(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('addedBtn') != null)
    document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '<input type="button"  
    value="Click" />';
    localStorage.setItem('addedBtn','anyValueYouWant')
  }
}
```

of course there are other solutions, but the other solutions i can imagine need a database, in this case the browser works as your local database.

hope it helps